# What is the inverse image of $\mathbb{N}$ under the real exponential function?

Tags: exponential-function, integers

$\exp (0)$ is an integer, and there is no other well known example of real number transformed into an integer through the exponential function.  Is $0$ the only one ?
I tried to study the $\ln (k) $ numbers with $k$ a positive integer, but I dont't find.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: $e^{\ln k}=k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number), $e^{a}$ is transcendental whenever $a$ is algebraic and nonzero.

Comment: @eranreches does your $\mathbb{N}$ include $0$?

Comment: @Gibbs I prefer $\mathbb{N}=\left\{1,2,3,4\dots\right\}$. Anyway, thanks! I should have stated that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if $m$ is a positive integer, $e^{\ln m} = m$. So $\exp^{-1}(\mathbb{N}) = \{\ln m: m \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}\}.$